# How to generate random place with jquery for google adverts

Tags: jquery, random

I have post items displayed 5 per row.How can I generate a random place for google advert and replace my 2 or 3 post items with google adverts but randomly.How I can do that?

Comment: Please show a little piece of your code

Comment: which part you want?I didnt imagie how I can do it.

Comment: The js code you have written

Comment: I havent written any code cause didnt know how to write the logic.can you help me with that

Comment: Ok, could you give me the html code of the posted item please

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88710/discussion-between-anahit-dev-and-zl3n).

Comment: Here is the fiidle link https://jsfiddle.net/c5xs16o1/

Comment: Do you want me to add the css also to that or only you need the structure?